# Extending service task in bpmn-engine ding-dong agi server nodejs

Tags: bpmn, agi, bpmn-engine

In the bpmn there is service task, i want to extend its functionality like based `type` attribute (`Method` | `API`)

if `API` then call to third party api can save the response in a variable.

and if `Method` then default behaviour like calling service method that i add in `bpmnEngine.execute({` under `services`

For this i added custom attributes like type, apiUrl and stuff

in case of API, i dont provide `implementation` attribute, so when agi server process the xml then it got stuck on service task.

How can i fix this, is there any way to do this?